# Parsing JSON object with JSON array inside it using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a Json reponse like this:

```
{
    "status" : "CREATED",
    "message" : "user created",
    "results" : [
        {
            "id" : "1243233",
        }
    ]
}
```

The above JSON response will be obtained with a POST call.In android using volley library i did a REST call as following:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                url, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.d("Request", response.toString());
                                        try {
                                            response.getString("status");
                                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");

                                                JSONObject id = (JSONObject)array.get(0);




                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.getString("status"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        pDialog.hide();

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                VolleyLog.d("Request", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                                pDialog.hide();
                            }
                        }){
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                return headers;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("phone", phone);
                                params.put("name", username);
                                params.put("pwd",password);
                                params.put("email", email);
                                return params;
                            }
                        };

                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

I am getting an error `org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 102 of`

```
 {
    "status" : "CREATED",
    "message" : "user created",
    "results" : [
        {
            "id" : "1243233",
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Your json is not valid Take a look here `"id" : "1243233",` - you have to remove coma on the end of this line.

Comment: @Manikanta android volley to better to user asynctask httpclient its so easy and speed to given responces

Comment: @Hardik Parmar you want me to use Async Task for background tasks instead of Volley?

Comment: @Manikanta you check this link for more information about async httpclient "http://loopj.com/android-async-http/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comma in the results array's item. Which means there should be another element(string,integer etc) as part of that JSONObject(first item of results array).

Hence you get the JSON parsing error.

```
    "results" : [
                   {
                     "id" : "1243233",
                    }
                ]
```

should be

```
   "results" : [
                 {
                      "id" : "1243233"
                 }
               ]
```

Removing comma

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am breaking my head from one hour :)